# Updating asp.net from a formview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, formview

I've been trying to figure this out for three weeks now but I'm struggling. I've googled every possible thing i could and have re-programmed this page several times. I am trying to update my database from a form view using the code behind using vb not c#.

The form populates fine from the database so i need to find out how to submit changes back to the database.

Here's my form:

```
 <asp:FormView ID="FormView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

                <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="CID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("CID") %>'>
                            </asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Heading" CssClass="label"></asp:Label> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Heading" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Heading")%>'>
                            </asp:TextBox>
                            <br /><br />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Content" CssClass="label"></asp:Label><br /><br /> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ContText" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="ckeditor" Text='<%# Bind("ContText") %>'>
                            </asp:TextBox>
                            <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Text="Update Section" />
                </ItemTemplate>               
             </asp:FormView>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Conn %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblContent] WHERE ([CID] = @CID)" UpdateCommand="Update tblContent SET Heading = @Heading, ContText = @ContText WHERE CID = @CID">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CID" QueryStringField="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Heading" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContText" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

It populates the data using a querystring reference called 'ID'. The code behind is currently blank because as i mentioned, it's been re-programmed several times so i removed all the code to stop confusion. I'm still new to asp.net and i'm losing the will to live with this! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now - i needed an edit template and this:

```
Private Sub FormView2_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As    System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewCommandEventArgs) Handles    FormView2.ItemCommand
    Try
        SqlDataSource1.Update()
    Catch except As Exception
        ' Handle the Exception.
    End Try
End Sub
```